# Update front-end when delete a row in database in React native

Tags: python, django, backend, manage.py, makemigrations

I am new with Django and I trying to run my first project. But i keep getting this error when trying to run python .\manage.py makemigrations

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBcSj.png)

I am not sure what is the problem

Comment: Try simply **python manage.py makemigrations**

Comment: The error is clearly telling you that `manage.py` file doesn't exists.